# Open source interactive geo viz and other options for d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, google-visualization, visualization

Are there any other open source visualizations similar to d3.js which are lighter and can handle more data, because the data i am trying to visualize is a large dataset and d3.js is taking a lot of time to load when hosted on a server.

Also i am in search of a interactive geographic visualization. Currently i am using google viz. but it is kind of inconsistent sometimes it loads sometimes it doesn't. I know there is a limit of no of calls that you can make but this reasons are not something that can be said professionally.

Answer (score 1):

While d3.js is beautiful as generic data visualization tool, it's not the best in case of specific visualization needs.
It really depends on the kind of visualization you want to show: for multiple visualization combined together I think that it's hard to find something better than d3... or maybe [RaphaelJS](http://raphaeljs.com/).
[PaperJS](http://paperjs.org/) is cool as well but it does perform more or like like d3.js IMHO.

What kind of visualization are you trying to make?
Maybe there's a specific library that can help you to handle your data easily.

For geographic visualization you can have a look to [LeafletJS](http://leafletjs.com/) (which is data provider agnostic) and has an entire [universe of plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html): most of them are designed to perform well also with millions of points.